# Vue Custom directive not working with template tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm facing issue with the below directive, it is working with any tag except the template tag

```
  Vue.directive('count',{
  bind(el,b,v){
    console.log(b.value);
  },
  inserted(el,b,v){
        console.log(b.value);
  },
  update(el,b,v){
        console.log(b.value);
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app"  ,
  data:{
     value:0
  }
})

<div id="app">
<button @click="value+=1">
inc value
</button>
   <template v-count="value">

   </template>

 <!--  <div v-count="value">

   </div> --> 
</div>
```

If the comment on the div is removed, the directive logs the value, but with the template tag directive's hooks are not triggered

Here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ms101/z3bgp8vu/1/) for the issue

Thanks

Comment: but the v-if directive is working even it is used on template @palaSH

Comment: you can hide the template and its children if the condition is true

Comment: ok I will explain, suppose that the <template> has children inside, and we put the v-if with a condition, if the condition is true, children are rendered which means the v-if directive is working on <template> with no issue, I tried to create a directive to remove any children within the template if I put my directive but the directive hooks are not triggered, same case is working if I used it on a div

Comment: yes, I understand that, I need my directive when it is used with the <template>, directive's hooks to be triggered but that it is not happening. you said that it is not supported when used with template tag but the v-if is working even it is used with the template. hope you got me

Comment: can you explain how the v-if hooks are triggered when it is used with template tag, it is not clear for me

Answer (score 0):

The template tag doesn't actually mount anything on its own, so it has no place in the DOM and doesn't bind. In your case, an easy solution is to just put v-count="value" on the button tag. If there is a more specialized need for this directive and you're just giving us placeholder code, putting it on a SPAN or DIV will make more sense than a template anyway.

Comment: actually using div or span may break the design especially inside a ul tag if you want to hide some li based on custom directive logic, my question why the v-if working even it is used on template tag

Comment: v-if and v-for work with templates, that's correct. I think I'm missing the point of your question, though. If this custom directive is about showing or hiding, that information is helpful to us (and better served using built-in v-if/v-show with a computed property).

Comment: My  question is about why the built-in v-if is working on a template, but any custom directive is not working whatever the logic of the directive, I can edit the question if it is not clear